# Use Integer.is_even(count) in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I customize the `phx.gen.html` template to use TailwindCSS. In the `:show` template I use this code:

```
<%= for {{k, _}, counter} <- Enum.with_index(schema.attrs) do %>
  <% bg_color = if Integer.is_even(counter), do: "bg-gray-50", else: "bg-white" %>
  <div class="<%= bg_color %>">
    [...]
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Running the generator results in this error message:

```
** (CompileError) ./priv/templates/tailwind.gen.html/show.html.eex:10: 
you must require Integer before invoking the macro Integer.is_even/1
    (elixir 1.11.2) expanding macro: Kernel.if/2
    ./priv/templates/tailwind.gen.html/show.html.eex:10: (file)
```

The `Integer.is_even(counter)` is the problem.

- How can I require `Integer` here?
- Is there a better/easier/cleaner way to iterate the value of `bg_color` between "bg-gray-50" and "bg-white"?

Comment: `<% require Integer %>` anywhere in `show.html.eex` before the call. Also, [`rem(counter, 2) == 0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#rem/2) is a plain function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% require Integer %>
<%= for {{k, _}, counter} <- Enum.with_index(schema.attrs) do %>
  <% bg_color = if Integer.is_even(counter), do: "bg-gray-50", else: "bg-white" %>
  <div class="<%= bg_color %>">
    [...]
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks to @aleksei-matiushkin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with tailwindcss, but this can typically be done purely through CSS.

It looks to me like tailwindcss does support an ["even-child" variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#even-child).

So I would imagine after a small tweak to your tailwind config you could just give all your divs the same class (I believe CSS child indices start at 1, so I'm flipping what's "even"):

```
<%= for {k, _} <- schema.attrs do %>
  <div class="bg-gray-50 even:bg-white">
    [...]
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is an interesting take on the problem. Thanks!